# Will loading my app from Eclipse to my Android phone instead of AVD will speed things up? Because AVD is slow as hell

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

AVD takes forever to load my app. So I was wondering if using my android cellphone would speed things up a bit.

Comment: yeah compared to emulator device running faster..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply said, it absolutely will.

Enable USB debugging on your device.

Install phone drivers and connect your phone to your PC. When running your application choose your phone from the list and run.

Read more about all steps on [Using Hardware Devices, Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Comment: Thanks! It's very fast!! Instead of waiting for minutes, I only wait for seconds :D